# Are "whereunto", "in which" and "whereto" all synonymous?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

This comes from Romantic Poets and the Culture of Posterity
By Andrew Bennett:

> Let us conclude with the dignity and excellency of knowledge and
>   learning in that **whereunto** man's nature doth most aspire; which is
>   immortality or continuance; for to this tendeth generation, and
>   raising of houses and families; to this tend buildings, foundations,
>   and monuments; to this tendeth the desire of memory, fame, and
>   celebration; and in effect, the strength of all other human desires'.

I find it weird that "whereunto" means the same thing as "in which" since I rarely hear "whereto" being used nowadays, and the words taken separately don't mean anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may carefully compare and contrast the meanings in various dictionaries and then consider if the question remains.

wiktionary.org:

> (archaic or formal, interrogative) unto what; to what purpose
>   (archaic or formal) unto which

dictionary.com:

> Archaic . whereto.
>
> whereto:
>   Archaic . to what or what place or end.
>   to which.

mirriam-webster:

> whereto
>
> whereto:
>   to what place, purpose, or end
>   to which

Next,

> Are "whereunto", "in which" and "whereto" all synonymous?

Almost. "whereunto", "to which" and "whereto" are synonymous.

> I rarely hear "whereto"

It is archaic.

> the words taken separately don't mean anything similar.

"to where" and "to which" don't mean anything similar? They appear a bit similar, if not exactly so.